# Textarea css not clickable

Tags: html, css

How to set the css of a textarea not to be clicked on it.

```
           <textarea></textarea>
```

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean with "not to be clicked on it"?

Comment: In readonly mode the cursor should not be focused on the textarea when clicked on it

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try

```
<textarea disabled="yes"></textarea>
```

In most browsers, this will grey out the content of the textarea though, and the user won't be able to copy any text from within it. If you don't like that, you can use:

```
<textarea readonly="yes"></textarea>
```

The textarea will then remain clickable, and the user will still be able to select/copy text within it, but he won't be able to edit it.

Comment: I believe it should be `<textarea disabled></textarea>` or `<textarea disabled="disabled"></textarea>`, likewise for `readonly`.

Answer (score 2):

So you don't want the user to edit the contents of the `textarea`? Simple solution: Don't use `textarea`. Just use a normal `div` or `pre` and style it.

Answer (score 1):

You Cant do this with CSS, you have to do it in the markup like so:

```
<textarea disabled="disabled"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you care to be By-The-Book & standard compliant it is as follows :

1. For "Unclickable"

   <textarea readonly>
   ...
    </textarea>
2. For "Grayed & unclickable" aka Disabled :

   <textarea disabled>
   ...
    </textarea>

You can find all other properties of "textarea" [here.](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_textarea.asp)